# KeyError when running python via file path, no issues when directly in directory

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am using a Ubuntu18 EC2 instance with AWS. I have installed Anaconda package.

When I am directly inside the appropriate directory and run `python code.py` it runs fine. However, it does not run when I try to run the script with a file path.

#### Actual Code:

**Works** 
`$ python AverageAmountofSessions.py`

**Not Working:** 
`$ python mycompany/AverageSessions/AverageAmountofSessions.py`

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycompany/AverageSessions/AverageAmountofSessions.py", line 126, in <module>
    lambda_handler('event','content')
  File "mycompany/AverageSessions/AverageAmountofSessions.py", line 28, in lambda_handler
    db_host = db_config['mysql']['host']
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 958, in getitem 
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'mysql'
```

**Addition Notes:**

- Calls two .ini files to get credentials to log into gmail and datawarehouse
- Libraries: SQLalchemy, matplotlib, pandas, smtplib, configparser

Comment: just see how your project is configured , which path it is taking  to intilaise the mysl path from the execution point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like it does not find the key mysql wich should be in your ini file.
Maybe the path to find your ini file in your scipt is not the good one

i mean if you open you ini file like that :

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.ini')
```

then the example.ini is not relative fro mwhere you python scipr is but from the $PWD which mean where you are in your shell when you run it !!

if you do something like that and the example.ini is in the same directory as you ini file

```
import os
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
conffile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'example.ini')
config.read(conffile)
```

Comment: This has most certainly helped. I after some banging my head off the desk I noticed that I needed to append "os" to the front of your conffile variable. Once I get it working I will come back to mark this as a certified answer with any addition point I can contribute. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are your ini files in the same directory as the python file. It certainly looks like it cant find the file. Id start by checking how your db_config dict is set. If that is the problem,a way around this would be to set the PYTHONPATH variable to the root folder of your source code